# Matrics manipulations

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, dataset

this is a basic question in Mathematica, I hope to get help to resolve it,
How I can extract elements from matrics for example
I have

```
list1 = {{"Dis", "S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S5", "S6"},
         {"D1", 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {"D2", 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {"D3", 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1},
         {"D4", 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {"D5", 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {"D6", 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
         {"D7", 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}};
List2 = {{"Dis", "S7", "S8", "S4", "S9", "S10", "S3", "S11", "S12", "S5", "S1"},
         {"D2", 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {"D8", 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
         {"D9", 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {"D10", 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
         {"D6", 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {"D11", 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1},
         {"D12", 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {"D13", 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1},
         {"D14", 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {"D15", 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
         {"D16", 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {"D17", 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}};
```

Imagine that D = represent Diseases 
the common diseases in between List 1 and List2 is

```
DL1 = Delete[List1[[All, 1]], {{1}}];
DL2 = Delete[List2[[All, 1]], {{1}}];
CommonD = Intersection[DL1, Dl2]
(* {D2, D6} *)
```

Does anybody have an idea can help me to extract all the element start with {"D2", "D6"} in order to obtain an output like this: from List1

```
{{"D2", 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {"D6", 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}}
```

Another list from List2

```
{{"D2", 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {"D6", 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}}
```

Anybody have any insight? Thanks!

Comment: `Cases[list1, {"D1" | "D6", __}]` and `Cases[list2, {"D1" | "D6", __}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use something like

```
Flatten[(s=#;Select[list1,First@#==s&]),1]&/@{"D2","D6"}
```

> {{"D2", 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {"D6", 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}}

Comment: thank you so much, but if the '''CommonD//Dimension= 1000 not just two elements like above, output like that ={D2, D6, D3, Dn}

Comment: this is not a problem.Just put `commonD` instead of `{"D2","D6"}` at the end of the code

Comment: I got output empty with error the out above{D2, D6} without double quote ,Flatten[(s = #; Select[List1, First@# == s &]), 1] & /@ {CommonD}

Comment: don't use brackets... just `...First@# == s &]), 1] & /@ CommonD`

Comment: Thanks J42161217 - that was incredibly helpful

Comment: One more question plz how add the fist elem from List1 to be the 1st elem into output CommonD..like `{{"Dis", "S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S5", "S6"},{"D2", 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {"D6", 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}}`

Comment: `Join[List1[[1]],Flatten[(s=#;Select[list1,First@#==s&]),1]&/@CommonD]`

Comment: or `Join[{List1[[1]]},Flatten[(s=#;Select[list1,First@#==s&]),1]&/@CommonD]` test them.one of the two will work

Comment: Thank you sooooo much

Comment: hello J42161217 again can you help me with this: I want to get output from List1 above like that: `{{D1,{S1,S3,S5,S6}},{D2,{S1,S3,S6}},{D3,{S3,S4,S6}},{D4,{S2,S5,S6}},{D5,{S1,S2,S3,S5,S6}},{D6,{S1,S2,S6}},{D7,{S2,S3,S6}}}`

Comment: @BenAawf Here it is (although you should have posted a new question...)    `{#,Pick[Rest@list1[[1]],{##2},1]}&@@@Rest@list1`    If this answer is what you were looking for you can accept it by clicking the tick below the answer score

Comment: #J42161217 I have this question I hope you can help me with it in the link: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/198815/how-to-join-two-matrix-with-different-dimensions